# Complex Sumifs Scenario?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I would like to calculate orders based on two criteria:

- Resource Code (In column B)
- Depot (In row 1)

In the example below I want to return total orders in cell `R5` for resource code "R0015" and depot "Folkestone".  Answer should be 120 (40 + 80).

I have tried `SUMIFS()` but can't get it working on any depots with two columns, such as Folkestone in this example.  Any help appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT`

`=SUMPRODUCT((I4:N28)*(B4:B28=R3)*(I3:N3=R4))`

Like this you can set conditions for the Resource Code (`B4:B28`) and the depost (`I3:N3`)

Answer (score 2):

Based on your `Excel Version` use either `SUM()` or `SUMPRODUCT()` the following:

[image]

---

```
=SUM((R4=I3:N3)*(B4:B19=R3)*I4:N19)
```